# What is the same-sheet equivalent of IMPORTRANGE?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

## Usecase

For a single google-sheet, let's say:

1. tab 1 has answers populated via google-form 1

   - say form-1 has two fields `A` and `B`
2. tab 2 has answers populated via form 2

   - form-2 has 2 other fields `A` and `C`
3. I want tab 3 to now have columns `A`, `B` & `C`

## Problem Statement

- When syncing up a column to another sheet, I want to manually copy-paste "values" on tab 3
- IMPORTRANGE has what I'm looking for, but just wanted to check with the community first.

Comment: Assuming A:A is to be unique (names for example), you could get a combined list `=Unique( { tab1!A:A; tab2!A:A } )` then use QUERY or FILTER or MATCH  to retrieve the values from the two sheets based on that list.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The `importrange()` function is not optimal for this. You will need an array formula or lambda. Please show two [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data from tabs 1 and 2, together with a table that shows your manually entered desired results you want to see in tab 3.

Comment: @doubleunary please refer this sheet: [stackexchange #168102 example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yocgXp2pNyh5hVEPbcaHXYPWJr6W4za1rfJKtnMIDhw/edit#gid=0) to see what I mean; tab form-1 and form-2 are the answers from 2 separate google forms. `ID` is some unique foreign key. the tab named `combined` shows my desired end state. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." Share it as "anyone with link can edit." There is also a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: apologies @doubleunary I thought I'd already done that. Permissions have been updated, I verified the sharing settings on incognito mode as well. :pray:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose **Insert > Sheet**, then put this formula in cell `B2` of the new sheet:

```
=unique( { 'form 1'!B2:B; 'form 2'!B2:B } )
```

...or manually paste or enter IDs in column `B2:B`.

Then put this `vlookup()` formula formula in cell `C2`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    iferror( 
      vlookup( 
        B2:B, 
        'form 1'!B2:D, 
        { 2, 3 }, 
        false 
      ) 
    ), 
    iferror( 
      vlookup( 
        B2:B, 
        'form 2'!B2:C, 
        2, 
        false 
      ) 
    ) 
  } 
)
```